# How to add new sub resource to a standard Intershop AbstractResourceObject

Tags: intershop

I want to introduce a new sub resource to standard Intershop ProductResource
without loosing the product resource context.

E.g In my resource's code, I want to know about the product to which a REST client is referring to `/product/SOME/my-sub-resource`

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a recipe in "Cookbook - REST Framework":

Add a Resource to an Existing REST API
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/28269L

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add a new java class extending `com.intershop.component.rest.capi.resource.AbstractRestResource`
2. Register the implementation in a component file

```
<implementation name="YOUR_NAME"
    implements="AbstractRestResource"
    class="YOUR_FQNAME_TO_IMPL_CLASS"
    factory="JavaBeanFactory">
    <requires name="name" contract="String" cardinality="1..1" />
    <requires name="subResource" contract="RestResource" cardinality="0..n" />
</implementation>
```

3. Instantiate the implementation in a component file

```
<instance with="YOUR_NAME" name="YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME">
    <fulfill requirement="name" value="YOUR_SUBRESOUCE_NAME" />
</instance>
```

4. Add as `subResource` to `intershop.WebShop.RESTAPI.ProductResource` instance

```
<fulfill requirement="subResource" 
    of="intershop.WebShop.RESTAPI.ProductResource" 
    with="YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME"/>
```

After that your resource is available under `/product/SKU/YOUR_SUBRESOURCE_NAME`. Make sure your impl class has a public method and that method is annotated with `javax.ws.rs.GET` and `javax.ws.rs.Produces`

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public SomeRO get()
{
    ApplicationBO applicationBO = provider.get();
    ProductBORepository productBORep = applicationBO.getRepository(ProductBORepositoryExtension.EXTENSION_ID);
    ProductBO product = productBORep.getProductBOBySKU(getParent().getName());
    // Do the stuff you want with the product
}
```